# Python using input() within function to determine data type

Tags: python, function, input, edx

I'm in one of the final chapters of my Introduction to Computer Science using Python. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code? The result is just **BLANK**.

```
#Write a function  called "input_type" that gets user input and 
#determines what kind of string the user entered.

#  - Your function should return "integer" if the string only
#    contains characters 0-9.
#  - Your function should return "float" if the string only
#    contains the numbers 0-9 and at most one period.
#  - You should return "boolean" if the user enters "True" or
#    "False". 
#  - Otherwise, you should return "string".

#Remember, start the input_type() function by getting the user's
#input using the input() function. The call to input() should be
#*inside the* input_type() function.


def input_type(userInput):
    digitTable = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    test1 = userInput.find(digitTable)
    if userInput == "True" or userInput == "False":
        return "boolean"
    elif test1 == -1:  # No digits
        return "string"
    elif userInput == "True" or userInput == "False":
        return "boolean"
    else:  # Contains digits
        test2 = userInput.find(".") # find decimal
        if test2 == -1:  # No decimals means it is an integer
            return "integer"
        else:  # Yes if float
            return "float"

userInput = input()
print(input_type(userInput))
```

Comment: You are not using what the users types in, you always pass in "0.23". `input_type()` either returns a string or `None`, therefore `print()` will print something more than blank if called. You don't seem to be executing this program if you get blank, therefore add a temporary `print("running ....")` at the top of your program, to make sure things get called/started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your's problem:

```
def input_type(userInput):
    digitTable = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    test1 = userInput.find(''.join([str(x) for x in digitTable]))
    if userInput == "True" or userInput == "False":
        return "boolean"
    elif test1 == -1:  # No digits
        return "string"
    elif userInput == "True" or userInput == "False":
        return "boolean"
    else:  # Contains digits
        test2 = userInput.find(".") # find decimal
        if test2 == -1:  # No decimals means it is an integer
            return "integer"
        else:  # Yes if float
            return "float"

userInput = input()
print(input_type("0.23"))
```

Comment: I get your code but the tutorial has not taught me some of this. I'll review this. I try to use what I learned from tutorial and try not to go out of my knowledge yet so I don't get confused.

Answer (score 1):

To improve your's code and make it shorter and nicer, you can do something like this:

```
import re

def input_type(userInput):
    if userInput in ("True", "False"):
        return "boolean"
    elif re.match("^\d+?\.\d+?$", userInput):
        return "float"
    elif userInput.isdigit():
        return "int"
    else:
        return "string"

res = input()
print(input_type(res))
```

Works for me :)

Comment: Did you use this on edX?

Answer (score 1):

Here is your error. 
When you run the program, it is waiting for an `input()`. You're supposed to enter something. So that is holding the entire program.
Another issue with your program. You have hard coded the parameters in `print(input_type("0.23"))`. So no matter what you input, it is going to be the same.

EDIT: Another suggestion. Please use a better logic for solving the problem. Just thinking about it and optimizing it will take you a long way in learning how to code in any language. :)

Comment: The exercise actually should provide a code for that tthat they held back until i hit "submit". I forgot to remove the [userInput = input()]. The print() was just used to test if my code worked.